# Hibernate Merge not refreshing collection and causing deletes

Tags: java, hibernate

Here are my classes

```
class Teacher {
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
Set<Students> getStudents()
}
```

The problem is,

**Session 1**

Step 1:Get Teacher id = 1, Initialize students by calling session.intitializeCollection(teacher.children) in the same session

Step 2: add a new Student (id =1)

Step 3: merge the teacher instance to cause insert of added student

**Session 2:**

Step 1: Get Teacher id = 1 before Step 2 in Session 1. Initialize children using intializeCollection(teacher.children)

Step 2: Perform a merge to get any changes done in Session 1 (after Step 3)

//at this step, hibernate id doing an update on Teacher and deletes Student 1

Step 3: add another Student (id = 2) and merge the teacher to save Student (id = 2)

I was assuming that when merge 2 is done in step 2, it would cause the collection to be refreshed with the changes done in Session 1 i.e. add the new object from Session 1 to Session 2, children collection.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how the object should be handled so that in Session 2, the students collection is refreshed with any changes to the table i.e. getting any child objects added to the table?

Also just a note, after Step 1, the teacher object is a detached instance, because the object is passed to the web based view layer and modified in Step 2 and re-attached in Step 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`The merge() method merges modifications made to the detached instance into the corresponding managed instance, if any, without consideration of the state of the persistence context. In other words, the merged objects state overrides the persistent entity state in the persistence context, if one is already present.`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1318)

getStudents is lazy, so the collection is never materialized in your session 2. When you call merge, it sees an empty collection and assumes that's what you want, so it removes the students from the persistent object. In session 2 you should make sure you call getStudents before merging or adding your new student.

Comment: I updated the steps, I do initialize the children collection in step 1, so I am assuming it cannot be a problem with lazy collections.

Comment: In session 2 you still have the collection without the student you are adding in session 1, that's why it's removed when you merge in session 2. You are not thinking about "merge" correctly. You say `Step 2: Perform a merge to get any changes done in Session 1 (after Step 3)` but that's not what merge does. Read the docs I pasted again. Based on the behavior, I'm guessing you don't have a version column for the entity? That may help alleviate this problem for you.

Comment: OK, looks like I totally misunderstood merge then. So what is the correct pattern to use in this case where the collection of children can be updated concurrently. I guess the best approach would be either directly insert the children and not use a cascade operation for merge on parent or to refetch the parent completely before any addition of children (if using merge)? The requirement is that the children can be added concurrently. I tried using version columns on both the parent and children but results in the same behavior.

Comment: The best approach is to have a version column. Hibernate or JPA will use that column. Then when you attempt to write the object, if your current version is different than the version in the database you will get an exception and you will then know that you are out of date, at which point you refresh your object from the databse, apply your changes again, and try again to save.

Comment: If I use version column, would it be on the Parent or on the child. In case I use it on the parent, would it be updated even if I don't make any changes to the parent object fields but just add/remove from the child collection?

Comment: have a look at the docs. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-optimistic  You are going to want a version on all your entities.

Comment: I am sorry but version is not working for me...I am reading somewhere that if you just add/delete from the child collection on the parent, then version on the parent is not updated. As a result in spite of using version on both parent and child entities, when I try to do a merge in session 2, instead of getting a staleobject exception, it is deleting the child added in session 1 and doing an insert of child 2 added in session 2